# how to measure calls count and elapsed time of code snippets

Tags: c++, profiling, profiler

Naturally I have my source code, and I am looking for something like QML Profiler (Qt Creator), but with pure C++ code. Do I have to write own code for that, or I can use some tools?

Most important for me are time & number of calls of functions in code

Edit: I am working on Windows 7, but there should be no problem to reboot into Ubuntu (I am not familiar with unix-like OS :( )

Edit2: I am trying to find some call-graph tools, on the first line I will try doxygen

Comment: Read about [profiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29), and see what options your compiler needs to enable that.

Comment: Visual Studio has a relatively decent built-in profiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a CPU profiler. I am using the [GNU gprof](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/).

Here are the small guide I use in this [link](http://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/profiling-tools/).

Here is a sample output I got from the profiler in my code (where you can see before actually running) that you get exactly what you want:

```
Flat profile:

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name    
 52.00      0.13     0.13        5    26.00    26.00  compute_variances(unsigned int, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > const&, int, unsigned int const&, float*, float*, unsigned int*)
....
....
 %         the percentage of the total running time of the
time       program used by this function.

cumulative a running sum of the number of seconds accounted
 seconds   for by this function and those listed above it.

 self      the number of seconds accounted for by this
seconds    function alone.  This is the major sort for this
           listing.

calls      the number of times this function was invoked, if
           this function is profiled, else blank.

 self      the average number of milliseconds spent in this
ms/call    function per call, if this function is profiled,
       else blank.

 total     the average number of milliseconds spent in this
ms/call    function and its descendents per call, if this 
       function is profiled, else blank.

name       the name of the function.  This is the minor sort
           for this listing. The index shows the location of
       the function in the gprof listing. If the index is
       in parenthesis it shows where it would appear in
       the gprof listing if it were to be printed.
```

[EDIT]

Do not worry for Linux!
Just open a terminal and do (if you have only one .cpp file)

```
g++ main.cpp -Wall -std=c++0x -p -pg -O3 -o myExe
```

and then follow the steps in my link.

For more files, just make a makefile, like this:

```
sr: main.cpp    polytope.cpp    quadtree.cpp
    g++ -Wextra -Wall -Wreorder -lm -o sr main.cpp polytope.cpp quadtree.cpp    IO.cpp
```

Always remember to use tabs instead of whitespaces in makefiles. My makefile is too simple. Googling can result in much better makefiles. Here sr the executable file.

As @MK stated, in Visual Studio, you can use their [profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx).

[/EDIT]

However, there are times, that you are interested in counting only the time. For this purpose you could something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <ratio>
#include <chrono>

int main ()
{
  using namespace std::chrono;

  high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

  std::cout << "printing out 1000 stars...\n";
  for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i) std::cout << "*";
  std::cout << std::endl;

  high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

  duration<double> time_span = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1);

  std::cout << "It took me " << time_span.count() << " seconds.";
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

or any other [method](http://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/1651-2/) found on my pseudo-site.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using GCC, then you've got [`gprof`](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/index.html) all you need to do is compile with `-pg`.  There's also the [Google Performance Tools](http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/cpuprofile.html).

Comment: I am trying with gprof, but I don't have required symbols (whatever it means)


    gprof.exe <path> has no symbols

Comment: @BartłomiejSobieszek Have you compiled your executable <path> with `g++` options `-pg`?

Comment: Let me second to get some fun with CMD

Comment: Ok, it seems to work and exe file was compiled, but I can see only exe file, what else I am looking for?

Comment: @BartłomiejSobieszek, why don't you check the link I have in my answer? It says what you have to do. Just for not getting Paul answering agan and again.

Comment: @BartłomiejSobieszek in the directory that has the newly generated `gmon.out` file from your `-pg` compiled <path> run, run `gprof <path>|less`